# VBA Copy a row from a Workbook to another

Tags: vba, excel

I know this issue has been solved a lot of time, but I can't fix it.

Here is my code :

```
Sub MàJ_Pluri()
'
' MàJ_Pluri Macro
'

'chemin vers fichier pluri = chemin2
    Range("U35").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("U36").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

    Dim chemin2 As String
    chemin2 = Range("U36").Value

    Dim chemin As String
    Année = Range("C4").Value

    Sheets("Création DC").Select
    Sheets("Suivi Pluri-annuel").Visible = True
    Rows("3:3").Select
    Selection.Copy

    Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
        chemin2 _
        , UpdateLinks:=0
'
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
'
    Dim LastRow As Integer
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$AT" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Année
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Select
    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert
    Range("A4").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Windows("Gestion DC projet V.2.2.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("Suivi Pluri-annuel").Select
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Visible = False
    Sheets("Création DC").Select
    Range("C2:D2").Select




End Sub
```

So basicaly, my goal is to open the sheet in the first Workbook, copy what is in the row 3, open the second workbook, insert a blank row beneath the 2nd row, and paste in this row (which is always the 4th). Everything is working except that nothing is copying in the row.

Do you have any ideas ? Help would be really appreciated !

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First open workbooks, assign them to variable and then do rest of the operations.

Nothing is copied because you're copying and then opening next workbook, so the copying method is automatically cleared.